# Altman Kleiman 1.18 potentially poorly worded

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

I have decided to revisit this text and solve some unfinished as well as new exercises from the updated editions and very quickly I stumbled onto something I don't quite understand with problem 1.18, which reads as follows in the 2021 edition of the book.

Let $R$ be a ring, $P := R[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ the polynomial ring in $n$ variables. Given $F = \sum a_{(i_1, \dots, i_n)} X_1^{i_1} \cdots X_n^{i_n} \in P$, formally set
$$ \partial F / \partial X_j = \sum i_j a_{(i_1, \dots, i_n)} X_1^{i_1} \cdots X_n^{i_n} / X_j. $$
Given $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in R^n$, set $\mathbf{x} := (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, set $a_j := (\partial F / \partial X_j)(\mathbf{x})$, and set $\mathfrak{M} := \langle X_1 - x_1, \dots, X_n - x_n \rangle$. Show $F = F(\mathbf{x}) + \sum a_j (X_j - x_j) + G$ with $G \in \mathfrak{M}^2$. First show that if $F = (X_1 - x_1)^{i_1} \cdots (X_n - x_n)^{i_n}$ then $\partial F / \partial X_j = i_j F / (X_j - x_j)$.

It is not quite clear to me what the purpose of $G$ and $\mathfrak{M}$ serve here, as this simply looks like the first order Maclaurin expansion of $F$ around $\mathbf{x}$ with higher order correction $G$, but $\mathfrak{M} = \mathfrak{M}^2$ if I'm not mistaken as ideals simply absorb themselves and it doesn't make sense to talk about $\mathfrak{M} \times \mathfrak{M}$ here.

We can of course write $F = \sum b_{(i_1, \dots, i_n)} (X_1 - x_1)^{i_1} \cdots (X_n - x_n)^{i_n}$ and this simplifies into $F = F(\mathbf{x}) + \sum_{(i_1, \dots, i_n) \neq (0, \dots, 0)} \dots$ as the $b_{(0, \dots, 0)}$ term simply evaluates to $F(\mathbf{x})$. We can then pretty easily just stick the $a_j (X_j - x_j)$ terms into our expression for $F$ and then absorb the opposite terms into the sum, which are clearly members of $\mathfrak{M}$ and thus $\mathfrak{M}^2$ but this just feels wrong as it doesn't really utilize the hint and $\mathfrak{M}^2$ does not really play a factor here. The solution at the end of the text proves the hint as well as gives a concrete form for $(\partial F / \partial X_j)(\mathbf{x})$ but does not prove anything related to the main statement. Is this problem just poorly worded then?

Comment: when the authors write $\mathfrak{M}^2$ they don't mean the cartesian product, but the product of $\mathfrak{M}$ with itself as an ideal in $R$. In that case $\mathfrak{M}^2\neq \mathfrak{M}$

Comment: oh it looks like I had a brain fart. $\mathfrak{M}^2$ is the ideal of all 2nd order terms or higher whereas $\mathfrak{M}$ represents the ideal of all degree 1 terms or higher.

Comment: well, the product of ideals gives you precisely this